# I need to get continuous input for this but when I use a while loop it breaks

Tags: python

I try to use a while loop after the prints in the main_function but the input only goes to "What do you want to buy" and breaks afterwards. Any tips or solutions??

I have tried to make an input function as such:
def inp():
    global use
    use = input('/>> ')
    inp()
And all that function in my main_func function after making the use variable global. This is python 3.7.1, I just can't figure out why it won't go any deeper that the first question.

```
import sys
import os


inventory = []
stock = ['spoon', 'fork']




def main_func():
    print('Welcome to the store, some ground rules before we begin:\n')
    print('1)No running, plz\n2)No stealing, your bad if you steal!!\nEnjoy')
    print('Commands: Sell, Buy, Exit')

    running = True
    while running == True:
        inp = input("/>> ")



        if inp == 'Buy' or inp == 'B' or inp == 'buy':
            print('What would you like to buy?: ')
            if inp == 'spoon' or inp == 'Spoon':  
                stock.remove('spoon')
                inventory.append('spoon')
                if 'spoon' not in stock and 'spoon' in inventory:
                    print('Successfully bought a spoon!')
            elif inp == 'fork' or inp == 'Fork':
                stock.remove('fork')
                incentory.append('fork')
                if 'fork' not in stock and 'fork' in inventory:
                    print('Successfully bought a fork')
        elif inp == 'Sell' or inp == 'sell' or inp == 'S':
            print('What would you like to sell?: ')
            if inp == 'spoon' or inp == 'Spoon' or inp == 'S':
                if 'spoon' not in inventory:
                    print("You can't sell something you don't have")
                if 'spoon' in inventory:
                    inventory.remove('spoon')
                    stock.append('spoon')
                    print("Successfully sold "+inp+".")
            elif inp == 'fork' or inp == 'Fork' or inp == 'F':
                if 'fork' not in inventory:
                    print("You can't sell something you don't have")
                if 'fork' in inventory:
                    inventory.remove('fork')
                    stock.append('fork')
                    print('Successfully sold Fork..')
        elif inp == "Exit" or inp == 'exit' or inp == 'quit':
            sys.exit()

main_func()
```

'''I know the code is poorly structured and bad, I just want to experiment with something'''

There are no error messages that pop up but after it ask "What would you like to buy" I input one of the items and it does nothing, it still gets input but doesn't react to the item I put in. Ex:

"What would you like to buy?: "
/>> spoon   #Press enter#
/>>         #It gets input again and does nothing#

Comment: A perfect example why you should write good code also while experimenting. The problem would likely not have occurred

Answer (score 0):

You are reading from the standard input only once in the code that you've provided and that is the line

```
inp = input("/>>")
```

After which you're *printing* the message "What would you like to buy?: " instead of creating a prompt.

You should be using the `input` method whenever you want to read from the standard input.

```
inp = input("What would you like to buy?: ")
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot, I forgot something so simple :)

Answer (score 0):

There's no error message, because there is no error. The code just does what you implemented.

After the first input of `Buy`, the condition

```
if inp == 'Buy' or inp == 'B' or inp == 'buy':
        print('What would you like to buy?: ')
```

is satisfied - but no other subconditions. Thus it reaches the point

```
inp = input("/>> ")
```

in the `while`-loop again. You enter `spoon`. This will change the variable `inp` from `Buy` to `spoon`. So this time, none of

```
if inp == 'Buy' or inp == 'B' or inp == 'buy':
```

or

```
elif inp == 'Sell' or inp == 'sell' or inp == 'S':
```

or

```
elif inp == "Exit" or inp == 'exit' or inp == 'quit':
```

is satisfied, so the `while` loop asks for input again.

Comment: This also helped quite a bit, I added more stuff and changed the code as some suggested and it works now :)